# How to display three list view in loop one by one automatic?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to display three `ListView` in loop one by one, with different data after **30 sec interval** change to next list view and auto scroll in each and every list view.


Any help regarding this would be really appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

For multiple view types you can use RecyclerView with multiple view types.
Recycler view has more uses over ListView.

Please check example https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example

Comment: I have three custom list view like each contains ten row and different column may be data on column is not fixed like first list view contain 3 text view second list view contains 5 column and third list view contain 7 column and auto scroll is possible or not. Same thing i done using j query

Comment: You are using 3 listviews because you have three kind of different view types ?
And you are trying to show these there listviews in vertically with auto scroll after every 30sec ?

Comment: hi, Updated answer.
If it is not solve your case let me know

Comment: Bro that is in one page but i want 3 different page like 3 list view and auto scroll from top to bottom when it reach to bottom new list view to open but time is fix like 30 sec or any cause this will come from db so i don't know how much data is there in each list view

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to loop statement in which you'll loop through the handler. Then you'll set a delay using the handler (**note I've set the delay for 30000ms which is equivalent to 30 seconds; therefore, adjust the figure to your requirement**).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        if(i == 0){
            //This will be the first loop
        }else if(i == 1){
            //This will be your second loop
        } else{
            //This will be the third and final loop
        }
    }, 30000);
}
```

You should write a method to set your listview and trigger that method within the run() function. But you can customize that functionality based on your own requirements/how you best understand it. Additionally, because you are going to use different parameters for the listview, you'll have to go through **if** statements to determine at which part of the loop you are as this will determine which listview is going to be set now.